# How to show any date formats in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I am getting the dates from API so i have included `23-10-2019` here i am getting the date showing that `01-01-1970` i have used moment and datetransform `angular datepipe` but nothing works out.

Here is the stackblitz code [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbxwax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Any help to show the date correctly in html file.

TIA.

Comment: What format you want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue**: Native HTML date picker needs the input in format `yyyy-MM-dd`. You supplied the value in `dd-MM-yyyy` format. Also the date transformation is not working since you haven't provided the input value for transformation in the required format.

**Solution**: String formatting applied to split the date into date parts and then constructed date object for formatting. Changed the format into `yyyy-MM-dd`.

**StackBlitz Solution**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr8apk

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Excellent this is working fine with all dates but a small edit new Date(+dateParts[2], +dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]),

Becoz you have selected date 23-10-2019 but result is 23-11-2019

Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah! JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. I forgot that. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I updated the same and working fine but the issue is after refreshing the page the dates are reflecting without page refresh the date is not working. Any help!.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the date format you get from the backend, javascript is not accepting the date format you provided `(23-10-2019)`, change this to `this.datePipe.transform('10-23-2019', 'dd-MM-yyyy');`. Also dont forget to add quotes around the date. FYI its accepting date in the `mm-dd-yyyy` format. You are supplying date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, that is the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```
    let myDate = "23-10-2019".replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")
    let newDate = this.datepipe.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'es-ES');
```